# Obtener el Response de un archivo PHP en JAVA

Tags: php, java, mysql

Hola soy nuevo usando PHP y Mysql y estoy realizando una aplicación en la que el usuario se registra, cual el usuario da click en registrar se envía su información a un archivo php con el método POST y se registra en una base de datos, el problema es que no se como hacer que el archivo php de una respuesta del estado de la operación, lo que quiero lograr es saber si el usuario se registro.

Le muestro lo que tengo.

Método java:

```
private void CreateUserEmailAndPassword(String Useremail, String EmailPassword, String URL){

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            "Creo aqui debo de capturar la respuesta del archivo, por lo que entiendo las respuesta se obtiene en String entonces pondria una condicional para saber cual es el estado del la operacion"

         if(response).equals("Operacion exitosa"){...}

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i("SendEmailNotification", "The error is " + error.toString());
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {


            Map<String, String> RegisterUserInfoMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            RegisterUserInfoMap.put("UserEmail", EmailGettedPrevious);
            RegisterUserInfoMap.put("UserPassword", PasswordGettedPrevious);

            return RegisterUserEmailAndPassowdMap;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


}
```

Y este es mi código php:

```
<?php

    include 'DBConexion.php';

    $UserEmail = $_POST['UserEmail'];
    $UserPassword = $_POST['UserPassword'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO `01`(`UserEmail`, `UserPassword`) VALUES ('$UserEmail', '$UserPassword')";

    $ejecutar = mysqli_query($link, $query);   

    if($ejecutar){

     "Creo que con esta condicional se si la operación se realizo exitosamente, pero no se como mandarla, ejemplo "Usuario creado exitosamente""

    }

?>
```

Este código si funciona y si guarda los datos en la BD solo quiero hacer la respuesta y obtenerla desde java (Android Studio).

Comment: echo "tu respuesta";

Comment: gracias pero y como la obtengo en java?

Comment: desde el response de donde invocaste al php

Comment: y solo hago un if(response.quals("Exitoso")){}

Comment: el response es un objeto, mira sus propiedades antes, supongo que sera algo como response.data o response.text

Comment: Es mejor que devuelvas algo sencillo, como `"true"`, o `"false"` (OJO, en este caso sería una cadena, no un booleano), y que evites los acentos y demás historias. Por ejemplo, en PHP: `echo "true";` y en Android: `if(response).equals("true"){...}` ... Para respuestas más complejas es mejor usar un `JSONObjectRequest`, pero ese es otro asunto.

Comment: Y si quisiera una respuesta mas compleja como seria con  JSONObjectRequest y como la obtengo desde java?

Comment: Tendrías que hacer unos pequeños cambios: en tipo de petición debería ser `JSONObjectRequest` en lugar de `StringRequest`, tendrías que leer un `JSONObject` en vez de un simple `String` y desde PHP tendrías que devolver un JSON válido con `json_encode`. Me parece que aquí hay varios ejemplos sobre peticiones de tipo `JSONObjectRequest`. De todos modos, si tienes dudas al respecto es mejor que las plantees en una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya logre que funcionara.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo fundamental es que el código Java y el código PHP sean coherentes entre sí. Si desde Java lanzas un `StringRequest`, debes responder con una cadena desde PHP para poder evaluar la respuesta sin dificultad.

Debido a que el asunto de los acentos podría ser problemático, para casos sencillos como este te recomendaría evitar respuestas con acento. Si se trata de evaluar una cadena simple, en lugar de responder `Operación exitosa`, responde con un `ok`, o un `done` o un `true`, o un `error` o `false` en caso de error.

Veamos un ejemplo:

### Java

```
    public void onResponse(String response) {
     if(response).equals("done"){...}
    }
```

### PHP

Vamos a simplificar con un ternario:

```
$status = mysqli_query($link, $query) ? "done" : "error";
echo $status;
```

En este caso, PHP emitirá `done` o `error` en caso de que la consulta haya ocurrido o no. He nombrado la variable `$status`, por coherencia.

Con esto debería bastar. Pero te dejo algunas recomendaciones:

1. Tu código es vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Considera usar consultas preparadas. *Inyección SQL* significa que un usuario mal intencionado podría hacer cualquier cosa (según su nivel de malicia y experiencia) en tu servidor, valiéndose de las variables que pasas directamente en la consulta.
2. Para una inserción no basta con verificar el resultado de `query()`, deberías verificar el número de filas afectadas. En algunos escenarios, `query()` podría no dar error, pero no ocurrir inserción.
3. Convendría validar que las variables del POST no estén vacías antes de proceder a la inserción.

Comment: Ok. y sabes como puedo verificar de donde proviene la información que es enviada mediante POST, para que solamente haga caso cuando la información solo provenga desde la app supongo que con esto le pondría mas seguridad.

Comment: @XxTavo16xX desde donde mandas los datos podrías enviar también algo así como una APIKEY y luego en el servidor recogerla y si no es la correcta, desestimar el proceso de los datos. O puedes trabajar con tokens basados en [OAuth](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.oauth.php)